# How to pass a mySQLi prepared statement to a function

Tags: php, function, session, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have a mySQLi prepared statement and a function I want to pass it to to check to see if the input meets the right format before executing it.  I have determined in my actual code that if I move the $stmt->execute() statement just outside of the function that it works, but inside the function it does not.  I know that an old school concatenated SQL string can be passed like this, but what is the right way to handle this with prepared statements?

```
  function validateForm($stmt, $inputType){
      // A bunch of stuff here to validate for $inputType.
      $stmt->execute();
  }

  $editSQL = "UPDATE mytable SET input1 = ?,  input2  = ?,  input3 = ? WHERE  thisID = ?";
            $stmt = $conn->prepare($editSQL);
            $stmt->bind_param('sibi', $input1, $input2, $input3, $thisID);
            $input1 = $vPara[1][5]; 
            $input2 = $vPara[2][5]; 
            $input3 = $vPara[3][5]; 
            $thisID = $_SESSION['thisID'];

            validateForm($stmt, $inputType);
```

The specific error I get is:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object
```

Comment: How does it fail?

Comment: waning to run the query from a validation function is weird. no one would usually do that

Comment: Are your variables all set and correct? And I assume that `editSQL` is actually `$editSQL`? Your prepared statement makes use of `$editSQL`, so I assume it's not a constant.

Comment: hard to say what this is `editSQL`. As shown, is a constant.

Comment: `$vPara` how / where are those populated from? and does the session array have value? question's unclear for a lot of reasons.

Comment: $vPara is a matrix of backend data generated to manage paginated reports and behaviors... all the values are already confirmed right, I'm just trying to convert a system that was designed to use concatenated queries to prepared statements and trying not to have to totally rewrite the whole structure.  As for the missing $, yes that was just a bad copy paste.  I tried to strip away some of the clutter since the actual code is a lot more complex than I wanted to paste.  The query was already working, the pasted code is just an example of what I mean.

Comment: Can the people who voted to close this please review the revised question?  I forgot to include the error message in the original post, and now this question is affecting my ability to post further questions.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see why it could potentially not work.
You mentioned that if you use execute outside of this function it works. So leave it the way it works because That's recommended due to [Single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

Your validator should not be responsible for executing statements but
only for what its name says = validation.

The only thing that validator should do is to return true or false
and upon that decision, you should make execution or not
so change your code to the following:

```
<?php

function isFormValid($inputType)
{
    // A bunch of stuff here to validate for $inputType.
    if (//test cases) {
        $validationResult = true;
    } else {
        $validationResult = false;
    }

    return $validationResult;
}

$editSQL = "UPDATE mytable SET input1 = ?,  input2  = ?,  input3 = ? WHERE  thisID = ?";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($editSQL);
        $stmt->bind_param('sibi', $input1, $input2, $input3, $thisID);
        $input1 = $vPara[1][5]; 
        $input2 = $vPara[2][5]; 
        $input3 = $vPara[3][5]; 
        $thisID = $_SESSION['thisID'];

if(isFormValid($inputType)) {
    $stmt->execute();
} else {
    //do error processing echo, trow exception etc
}

?>
```

Note that I changed the validator name, so now it really expresses what it does, instead of being called `validateForm` but actually doing also a statement execution.

Comment: why even prepare and bind if the inputs are wrong, shouldn't you validate first?

Comment: @IdontDownVote you're right, validation should be done way before preparing statements - if the data is invalid then it does not make any sense to prepare statemetns

Comment: `return $validationResult` there should be closure here. Otherwise, it'll throw a parse error.

Comment: @Funk Forty Niner corrected that typo

Comment: thanks @Jimmix I saw that and fixed a few typos :-)

Comment: Thanks, I will try this in the morning when I get back to work.

Comment: This works.  Looks like this system has a few separation of GUI and Back-end issues that will require some additional reworking, but I can handle it from here. Thanks!